# How to display default text when translation is missing using jhiTranslate

Tags: jhipster

in JHipster application I want to display a default text within a html element when a translation is missing.

I use angular ngFor directive to display elements in an array, some of which have a translation and some of which are inserted by a user, and therefore have no translation in i18n json. I couldn't find any documentation that explained how to use jhiTranslate

I was thinking about syntax like this

```
<div jhiTranslate="example.1">Default Text</div>
```

and if this particular translation was missing a "Default Text" would be shown. for now it shows "translation-not-found[example.1]".

Is there a way to achieve this using jhiTranslate?

Comment: jhiTranslate is a JHipster directive on top of ngx-translate, have you considered using ngx-translate API directly to fit your own needs?

Comment: yes, however in my case it would require to change too much in my current project. In the end I found a workaround by using "[translateValues]". So the final result was something like <div jhiTranslate="example.1" [translateValues]="{value: value}"></div>. But still a default text would be the easiest solution for me.